# How does instance_eval work and why does DHH hate it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

At about the 19:00 mark in [his RailsConf presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0iKYRKtAsA#t=19m0s), David Heinemeier Hansson talks about the downsides of `instance_eval`:

> For a long time I ranted and raved
>   against `instance_eval`, which is the
>   concept of not using a yielded
>   parameter (like `do |people|`) and
>   just straight `do something` and then
>   evaluate what's in that block within
>   the scope of where you came from (I
>   don't even know if that's a coherent
>   explanation)
>
> For a long time I didn't like that
>   because it felt more complex in some
>   sense. If you wanted to put your own
>   code in there were you going to
>   trigger something that was already
>   there? Were you going to override
>   something? When you're yielding a
>   specific variable you can chain
>   everything off that and you can know
>   [you're] not messing with anybody
>   else's stuff

This sounded interesting, but a) I don't know how how `instance_eval` works in the first place and b) I don't understand why it can be bad / increase complexity.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The thing that `instance_eval` does is that it runs the block in the context of a different instance. In other words, it changes the meaning of `self` which means it changes the meaning of instance methods and instance variables.

This creates a cognitive disconnect: the context in which the block runs is not the context in which it appears on the screen.

Let me demonstrate that with a slight variation of @Matt Briggs's example. Let's say we're building an email instead of a form:

```
def mail
  builder = MailBuilder.new
  yield builder
  # executed after the block 
  # do stuff with builder 
end

mail do |f|
  f.subject @subject
  f.name    name
end
```

In this case, `@subject` is an instance variable of *your* object and `name` is a method of *your* class. You can use nice object-oriented decomposition and store your subject in a variable.

```
def mail &block
  builder = MailBuilder.new
  builder.instance_eval &block
  # do stuff with builder 
end

mail do 
  subject @subject
  name    name # Huh?!?
end
```

In *this* case, `@subject` is an instance variable of the *mail builder* object! It might not even *exist*! (Or even worse, it *might* exist and contain some completely stupid value.) There is *no way* for you to get access to *your* object's instance variables. And how do you even *call* the `name` method of your object? Everytime you try to call it, you get the *mail builder's* method.

Basically, `instance_eval` makes it hard to use your own code inside the DSL code. So, it should really only be used in cases where there is very little chance that this might be needed.

Comment: This is a good explanation but there are situations I found that you have no other choice but to use instance_eval, for the very reason that the proc objects were created in another context, but you want to run them in a completely different context.

Comment: I think this is most useful when creating small DSLs. https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines does this very effectively.

Comment: One very handy feature of `#yield` variant is that using the proper YARD tag one can get methods autocompletion.

Answer (score 19):

Ok, so the idea here is instead of something like this

```
form_for @obj do |f|
  f.text_field :field
end
```

you get something like this

```
form_for @obj do 
  text_field :field
end
```

the first way is pretty straight forward, you end up with a pattern that looks like this

```
def form_for
  b = FormBuilder.new
  yield b
  b.fields.each |f|
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

you yield out a builder object that the consumer calls methods on, and afterwards you call methods on the builder object to actually build the form (or whatever)

the second one is a bit more magical

```
def form_for &block
  b = FormBuilder.new
  b.instance_eval &block
  b.fields.each |f|
    #do stuff
  end
end
```

in this one, instead of yielding the builder to the block, we take the block and evaluate it in the context of the builder

The second one increases complexity because you are sort of playing games with scope, you need to understand that, and the consumer needs to understand that, and whoever wrote your builder needs to understand that. If everyone is on the same page, I don't know that it is nessicarily a bad thing, but i do question the benefits vs the costs, i mean, how hard is it to just tack on an f. in front of your methods?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that it's a little dangerous in that you can never be quite sure you're not going to break something without reading all the code that deals with the object your using instance_eval on.

Also if you , say, updated a library that didn't change the interface much but changed a lot of the object internals you could really do some damage.