# Why is my define_method not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I have two methods in my `Designer` class (in my rails app):

```
  def add_specialty(specialty)
    specialty_list.add(specialty)
    save
  end

  def add_qualification(qualification)
    qualification_list.add(qualification)
    save
  end
```

Here are specs I have for them that are passing:

```
  context 'adding specialties' do
    it "can add a new specialty" do
      expect { designer.add_specialty("interior design") }.to change {designer.specialty_list.count}.by(1)
      expect(designer.specialty_list).to include("interior design")
    end
  end

  context 'adding qualifications' do
    it "can add a new qualification" do
      expect { designer.add_qualification("architect") }.to change {designer.qualification_list.count}.by(1)
      expect(designer.qualification_list).to include("architect")
    end
  end
```

Now I want to refactor to this implementation:

```
  ["specialty", "qualification"].each do |attr|
    define_method("add_#{attr}") do |arg|
      "#{attr}_list".add(arg)
      save
    end
  end
```

This fails. I get failures:

```
  1) Designer adding qualifications can add a new qualification
     Failure/Error: expect { designer.add_qualification("architect") }.to change {designer.qualification_list.count}.by(1)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `add' for "qualification_list":String
     # ./app/models/designer.rb:93:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Designer>'
     # ./spec/models/designer_spec.rb:79:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/designer_spec.rb:79:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'

  2) Designer adding specialties can add a new specialty
     Failure/Error: expect { designer.add_specialty("interior design") }.to change {designer.specialty_list.count}.by(1)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `add' for "specialty_list":String
     # ./app/models/designer.rb:93:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Designer>'
     # ./spec/models/designer_spec.rb:72:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/designer_spec.rb:72:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong in my `define_method` implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"#{attr}_list"` by itself is just the string `"specialty_list"` or `"qualification_list"`, and strings don't have an add method. I think you want to the `send` the `specialty_list` method e.g.

```
%w{ specialty qualification }.each do |attr|
  define_method("add_#{attr}") do |arg|
    send("#{attr}_list").add(arg)
    save
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh yeah! this is much better. the `self` to which we are sending is the instance of the class - correct? Also is it dangerous to use `instance_eval`?

Comment: Yep, exactly, the implied `self` receiver is the instance of the class. I don't think of `instance_eval` as dangerous, just probably better suited to a different use case (needing to force the value `self`). [Some additional info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071532/how-does-instance-eval-work-and-why-does-dhh-hate-it/3071983#3071983).

Answer (score 0):

Ok: I got it working like this:

```
  ["specialty", "qualification"].each do |attr|
    define_method("add_#{attr}") do |arg|
      instance_eval("#{attr}_list").send(:add, arg)
      save
    end
  end
```

Not sure why this worked though or if its the right way to do it. Would anyone care to contribute towards a better understanding?

Comment: @Ben, I tried to use `send` but it still complained. I think I needed to `instance_eval` it to call the underlying method - not sure