# How can I access an instance variable inside of a Ruby block?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
class MyXmlReader

  attr_accessor :filename, :lines

  def initialize(filename)
    @filename = filename
    @line_hash = {}
  end

  def read
    reader = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(open(@filename))
    Xml::Parser.new(reader) do
      ... do stuff
      @line_hash[var] = line           # ERROR!
    end
  end

end
```

It looks like the block runs in a new scope. Because I'm getting:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

This is easily worked around by creating local variables and then assigning those variables to the instance variables at the end of the `read` method. But I'm wondering why a local variable is accessible within the block, but not an instance variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interesting question isn't so much why the local variable is accessible inside the block (of course it is, blocks are closures, having access to local variables from the surrounding scope is kind of the point), but rather why the instance variable isn't. Because, actually, it *should* be accessible.

However, *if* the block is being `instance_eval`ed or `instance_exec`ed, then the value of `self` will be changed to the receiver of the `instance_eval` or `instance_exec` message, and instance variables are always looked up in `self`, so since `self` is now a different object, it probably won't have an `@line_hash` instance variable. You would have to look at the implementation of `Xml::Parser::new` to find out.

See also [How does `instance_eval` work and why does DHH hate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3071983/2988)

Comment: That's an excellent, excellent description of why it happened the way it did. Makes perfect sense now.

Comment: See also [How does `instance_eval` work and why does DHH hate it?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3071983/2988)

Answer (score 3):

It is because local variables, unlike instance variables, have lexical scope. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope) may help.

Comment: The interesting question isn't so much why the local variable is accessible inside the block (of course it is, blocks are closures, having access to local variables from the surrounding scope is kind of the point), but rather why the instance variable isn't. Because, actually, it *should* be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem. Here is a simple test case, I created:

```
          class MyReader

            def initialize
              @line_hash = {}
            end

            def read
              [1,2].each do |x|
                @line_hash[x] = '0'
              end
            end

          end  

          p MyReader.new.read
```

Comment: That's because the "each" block does not execute in a separate context.