# How does title method inside TkRoot block work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I know this is a weird question. But I have been scratching my head when thinking about how a method called title is defined inside `TkRoot.new { title('Something') }`

Ok so here's a sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'tk'

p defined?(title)    # => nil
root = TkRoot.new { p defined?(title) } # writes "method" to stdout.
```

[Here's a link to the official guide](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html)

I have looked into the source code, which seems very very messy (and perhaps filled with all the bad practices to make the code harder to read) and filled with warnings when all the warnings are on.

My question is how the method definition works only inside the block? Can I get a small sample code here which shows how to restrict a method definition only to a block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to this black magic is [`instance_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval), which will evaluate the block in the context of its receiver. Normally `self` inside a block will be determined by scope; `instance_eval` will change the `self` inside its block to be whatever received the `instance_eval` message.

```
class Dog
  def bark
    puts "Woof"
  end

  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

Dog.new { bark }
# => "Woof"
```

In this case, `instance_eval(&block)` is the same as `self.instance_eval(&block)`, which means `self` inside the block will be the `Dog` instance; then `bark` is of course `self.bark`, where `self` is the `Dog`.

There is a school of thought that `instance_eval` is [harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071532/how-does-instance-eval-work-and-why-does-dhh-hate-it). I agree that it is best to limit its use to clearly delineated DSLs. I.e. it may work for TK, RSpec or Sinatra, but if you think it's cool and want to use it, it's good to think twice.