# How to call Class methods in block?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

```
class ShoppingList
  def add(a,b)
    print a,b
  end
  def items(&block)
    block.call
  end
end

s1 = ShoppingList.new
s1.add(4,10)
s1.items do 
  add(5,2)
end
```

undefined method `add' for main:Object

(repl):19:in `block in '

(repl):12:in `items'

how to call add in block ?..

Comment: This feels like a potential XP problem to me... Why would you want to call `add` in this way? Your code would also work by writing: `s1.items { s1.add(5, 2) }` - but it's hard to see what that's actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I would expect `s1.items` to return something like an `Array`, not yield a block. If you wanted to iterate over the items, I'd expect to write `s1.items.each { |item| ... }`.

Comment: _"How to call Class methods in block?"_ – although `add` is defined within a class, it's an instance method, not a class method. The latter is a method you invoke directly on a class like `ShoppingList.new`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to call `block` in the context of the `items` message recipient, you can use `instance_eval`:

```
def items(&block)
  instance_eval(&block)
end
```

Comment: Please note that, as David Heinemeier Hansson once said ["`instance_eval` is evil"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3071532/2988). Now, I don't fully agree with such an absolute statement (and to be fair to DHH, in the presentation, he wrote was only using this as a catch phrase and *did* go into substantive detail), I would rather say "`instance_eval` has some serious implications and using it without a full and detailed understanding, and a complete documentation of the implications for the user of your method (`items` in this case) is evil".